# Magento upgrade to 2.4.4 error on setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4

On upgrading to Magento 2.4.4 got this error on running setup:upgrade command

`Class "Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\Reader\XmlReader" does not exist`

This class is not used in any of the custom modules

The class is present in vendor/magento/framework/Communication/Config/Reader/XmlReader.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would firstly clear the generated folder, delete the vendor folder, run `composer cc && composer install` and then run `setup:upgrade`

Comment: Yupp...for some reason container-interop directory was missing inside vendor. So deleting the entire vendor directory and running composer install worked

Comment: Any ideas why this would not work? I tried and same error. I have 2.4.5-p1.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to download the 2.4.5-p1 version's original app/etc/di.xml file and copy that to my installation and then run setup:upgrade again.